# What is the simplest way to gather twitter data ongoing?

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I would like it to go into a google sheet. I thought I'd give super metrics a try, but it doesn't return data related to my keyword. I'm using the free trial to try it out.

With SuperMetrics I tried two ways. 1 - I set up my own query and got results. When I refresh it, it clears out the past results. 2 - I used a SuperMetrics template, and when I refresh, the data doesn't refresh - it just shows the SuperMetrics sample data. I have edited the query tweets. the query sheet shows "results contain sampled data" but the results are not related to my query.

I want to analyze the data for a non-profit.

Many thanks!

Comment: This seems more troubleshooting a specific product rather than the real question on gathering Twitter data.  Can you rephrase?

Comment: I didn't mean to make it so specific to SuperMetrics - I was trying to pre-empt comments about using that tool.
I'm just looking for a reliable way to capture tweets by certain users (and not get sampled data) and/or hashtags.
Does that help? 
P.S. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this tutorial does what you want.

"How to Save Tweets for any Twitter Hashtag in a Google Sheet"

http://www.labnol.org/internet/save-twitter-hashtag-tweets/6505/

I have used an older version of this and it worked so-so (it didn't store all the attributes that are available or that I wanted, and postprocessing in a google sheet is awkward). I've switched to using the twitter APIs directly (and saving twitter data in JSON notation to files).

Comment: Thank you. I use the free version of that. It might be worth it to go with the paid version.

Answer (score 2):

Would a database like this one be helpful? See https://www.quandl.com/data/TWITTER. It shows official Twitter statistics for 100,000 companies including followers, following, favorites, tweets and list counts. The database should also be downloadable in any format.

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]

Comment: Thank you - it's for a smallish non-profit (3million operating budget) based in a medium sized town, so I doubt it would be on anyone's top 100,000 companies.